# My C++ iteration will not function correctly

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to get a bunch of numbers then print them in ascending order in my C++ console application. Here is the code.

```
void test_compare()
{
    int amount;
    amount = 10;
    double num[amount];
    double dummy[amount];
    double smallest;
    int i;
    int inside_iterator;
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        cout << "Number " << i+1 << ": ";
        num[i] = get_double();
        cout << endl;
    }
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        for(inside_iterator=i;inside_iterator<amount;inside_iterator++)
        {
            if (inside_iterator == i)
            {
                smallest = num[inside_iterator];
            }
            else
            {
                if (num[inside_iterator] < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = num[inside_iterator];
                }
            }
        }
        dummy[i] = smallest;
    }
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        cout << endl << dummy[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I know, it's a mouthful...
But when I run it it outputs the last number all around. I did a trace to try and find the problem, but nothing comes up.

Thanks to anyone that helps.

Comment: Use `std::sort`. Declare variables close to use (`int i = 0;` instead of `int i; ... i = 0;` etc) Don't use non-standard VLAs; use `std::vector` if it has a runtime size.

Comment: Your logic seems flawed to me: First you look for the smallest number among all elements of `num` and write that into `dummy[0]`. Then you write the smallest number among the 2nd to the last element of num to `dummy[1]`. Then the smallest number among the 3rd to last element of num to `dummy[2]`. And so on... why should that give you a sorted list of numbers? You are removing the numbers from the to-be-searched set of numbers in the order they appear in `num`. If you want to do it like this at all, then you have to remove the number you found. But even bubble-sort is more efficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You need to swap the values inside "if (num[inside_iterator] < smallest)"

```
int main()
{
        int amount;
    amount = 10;
    double num[amount];
    double dummy[amount];
    double smallest;
    int i;
    int inside_iterator;
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        cout << "Number " << i+1 << ": ";
        num[i] = get_double();
        cout << endl;
    }
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        for(inside_iterator=i;inside_iterator<amount;inside_iterator++)
        {
            if (inside_iterator == i)
            {
                smallest = num[inside_iterator];
            }
            else
            {
                if (num[inside_iterator] < smallest)
                {
                    double tmp = smallest;
                    smallest = num[inside_iterator];
                    num[inside_iterator] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        dummy[i] = smallest;
    }
    for(i=0;i<amount;i++)
    {
        cout << dummy[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but could you further expand on what happened please? And, BTW, how do I rate you up?

Comment: Basically, what you want to do is swap the smallest with num[inside_iterator]. You were missing the swapping.